# C# Reading from MySQL repeats the same line

Tags: c#, mysql, database, logging

Just some "hopefully" simple questions.

Problems:
1. Data read repeats only 1 line non-stop.
2. How can I only append new entries in the database to my text box?

I'm trying to write a small tool that reads from my database every once in a while and populates my text boxes with the response data. The routine works, but only displays 1 line in my text box, and when called upon again, repeats the same line over and over.

I'm using the same routine (slightly altered) to read from the user chat log which is also stored in the database, and it seems to work fine.

I can't for the life of me find any decent documentation on only appending new data in the database to my log files. If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
    private void GMAudit()
    {
        //Get Connection Information
        IniFile ini = new IniFile();

        string SERVER = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "ServerIP");
        string USER = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "Username");
        string PASS = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "Password");
        string DB = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "Database");

        //Set Connection Information
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection GMAuditConnection;
        string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString = "server=" + SERVER + ";" + "uid=" + USER + ";" + "pwd=" + PASS + ";" + "database=" + DB + ";";

        //Connect to MySQL Server
        GMAuditConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        GMAuditConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        GMAuditConnection.Open();

        //Send Query
        string queryGMAudit = "SELECT Speaker, type, datetime, SUBSTRING(commandline,1,2000) FROM audit_gm Limit 25;";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand GMAudit = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryGMAudit, GMAuditConnection);
        GMAudit.CommandText = queryGMAudit;

        //Connect the Reader to the Database
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
        rdr = GMAudit.ExecuteReader();

        //Populate the Textbox Log
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                var txt = txtGM.Text;
                var str0 = "";
                var str1 = "";
                var str2 = "";

                //Break Colums into Strings
                var strNewLine = Environment.NewLine;
                str0 = rdr[0].ToString();
                str1 = rdr[1].ToString();
                str2 = rdr[2].ToString();

                byte[] byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(rdr[3]);
                String s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBLOBData);

                //Combine Columns into a Single String & Append to Text Box
                txtGM.AppendText(str0 + " " + str1 + " " + str2 +  " " + s + strNewLine);

                rdr.NextResult();               
            }
        }
        if (rdr != null)
        {
            rdr.Close();
        }

        //Disconnect from MySQL Server
        GMAuditConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to put or use a counter to be honest. I have very limited knowledge of MySQL and have only recently picked up C# again.

Comment: how come you have not graduated to using `.Config` File also have you stepped thru the code.. I wonder if you have an error in one of the lines.. I am thinking one of these 2 lines perhaps 
`byte[] byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(rdr[3]);
                String s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBLOBData);`

Comment: You're overwriting your variables while looping through your reader. You should add the values to something like an ArrayList.

Comment: Those 2 lines are to convert the blob data to a readable string, calling it directly .ToString(); fails miserably. My choice of file type is personal preference.

Comment: did you use the debugger.. set a few break points is where I would start your code up til the byte[] looks fine rdr[3] what's in that field is that actually a Blob field from the db ? looks like that's not being casted or converted properly

Comment: those lines work and convert the data properly, my only issue is it's repeatedly printing the same line instead of the rest of the table.

Comment: reading the Binary field you may fail if it does look at this link [SqlDataReader.GetSqlBinary Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbinary.aspx)
`rdr.NextResult();` change to `rdr.Next();` you're not returning multiple query results sets btw

Answer (score 1):

`rdr.Read()` should advance the cursor. `rdr.NextResult()` moves the cursor to the following resultset (if your query returned multiple sets), so when you execute that line the reader breaks out of the while loop on next iteration.

FYI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i'm using the same method in my chat log and it's working perfectly. rdr.Next(); does not exist as a command.

Comment: @user3614476 my mistake, I meant `rdr.Read()`.

Comment: txtChat.AppendText(str0 + " " + str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3 + " " + str4 + " " + str5 + strNewLine);

                    rdr.NextResult();            this works perfectly fine, not sure why it just won't work in the other table

Comment: it works most likely because you are traversing a single row result. All you need to do to solve the one line problem is to comment out `rdr.NextResult();`

Comment: i can assure you i'm not. i'm reading every row from a table, and NextResult() is required to move to the next line. Removing it only causes the application to spazz out

Comment: do you use more than one reader variable? You may be executing NextResult on a different reader than what populates txtChat. Would you mind posting the code for this?